# Md-dialog not loading the controller associated with it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mddialog

I am trying to load md-dialog in angular js1.5 when on click of button and all i see is the html markup in modal pop up but not the controller loads for that component. Following is my markup for showing the md-dialog
**File which calls the dialog**

```
 $mdDialog.show ({
        template: require('../traderdialog/traderdialog.html'),
        controller: Controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        locals : {
            traderId : traderId
        },
        clickOutsideToClose : true
        });
    }
```

So when I do controller :Controller it goes to different component as I have in my directory structure . **My code for traderdialog.js** follows as

```
 angular.module('dashboard')
.component('traderdialog', {
    template: require('./traderdialog.html'),
    controller: Controller,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindings: {

    }
});

function Controller( $mdDialog) { *some code* }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mdDialog.show ({
        template: require('../traderdialog/traderdialog.html'),
        controller: function ControllerName($scope){
                    $scope.data = "Controller Loaded";
         },
        locals : {
            traderId : traderId
        },
        clickOutsideToClose : true
        });
    }
```

**OR**

```
 $mdDialog.show ({
            template: require('../traderdialog/traderdialog.html'),
            controller: controllerName,
            locals : {
                traderId : traderId
            },
            clickOutsideToClose : true
            });
        }
    function controllerName($scope){
                        $scope.data = "Controller Loaded";
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inject the data you want from the parent controller to the the scope of modal. When modal opens it has its own scope.

```
$mdDialog.show ({
    template: require('../traderdialog/traderdialog.html'),
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    locals : {
        traderId : traderId
    },
    clickOutsideToClose : true
    });
}
```

Now, lets define your controller for you modal `traderdialog.html`.

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl',['traderId', function(traderId){
    console.log(traderId);
}]);
```

Now the `traderId` will reflect on your modal.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to use controller in mdDialog, one of them is use same scope with the parent in preserve scope:

```
$mdDialog.show({
          controller: function () {
            return self;
          },
          templateUrl: 'templates/mdDialog.html',
          parent: angular.element(document.body),
          targetEvent: ev,
          clickOutsideToClose: false,
          bindToController: true,
          scope: $scope,
          hasBackdrop: true,
          preserveScope: true
        });
```

another one is use with controllerAs attribute, and initialize it:

```
$mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        templateUrl: 'templates/mdDialog.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        controllerAs: 'DlgCtrl',
        bindToController: true,
        locals: {
          formData: $scope.formData,
        }
      })
```

and you can reach your locals with DlgCtrl.formData syntax.